# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, tomcat 7, java 7/8 problems

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

I know there are tons of these questions. I have been through a lot. I have been stuck on this issue for >24 hours.

I am using:

- Windows 8.1, 64bit
- Eclipse as IDE
- Tomcat 7

I want to do:

Make a small website with 4 pages that loads data from an sql server and some other simple stuff. The java code works if I run it as plain java in Eclipse.

The code also works if I run it in the JSP project with java 8 on localhost.

However, I need to host it on a java 7 server. I cannot update the server.

First I tried just uploading it anyway (by exporting to .war and uploading that), but that did not work. Then, I set all settings (preferences/java/compiler, preferences/java/installed JREs) to java 7 while using java 8. Projects are not overriding the default.

Setting my localhost to java 7 settings makes the localhost JSP unable to work too (same error), but it still works in plain java on my computer.

I have tried cleaning temporary/compiled files to force a recompilation (project/clean). I have done this every time between trying new things.

I am importing the classes to the JSP server using:

```
<%@ page import="jdbc.Publication"%>
<%@ page import="jdbc.SQLPublicationMapper"%>
```

and these are the names of my classes. The classes are in the `WEB-INF\classes` folder in the JSP folder. I copy them from the `jdbc\bin\jdbc` folder from the other project after compiling them.

There are no compilation errors.

There are no relevant warnings. They all concern HTML formatting stuff.

I have tried to completely uninstall java 8 and only have java 7 installed (JRE and JDK), but still I get the same error. Yes, I have recompiled the files after this.

I am running out of ideas to try. This makes no sense to me.

I am not normally a java developer, I code in R/python/php/js, so please give answers I can understand.

Any ideas?

Comment: That message means that the code was compiled with a version of Java (8) that is later than the Java runtime (7).  If you need this to run in a Java 7 environment, then you need to make sure that you compile with Java 7 as well.

Comment: Yes I know. As you can see, I have uninstalled java 8 and only have java 7 installed and yet it doesn't work.

Comment: If you uninstalled Java 8 and installed Java 7 with appropriate environment variables, Restart the eclipse and Click on Project -> Clean. Also Right click on project, then Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries Tab. Make sure it's having Java 7 jdk / jre. If it's Java 8 jdk / jre, remove it and then add java 7 library.

Comment: I have already done these. I have also restarted my computer multiple times, just in case.

Comment: Make sure that all your code is compiled with JDK 7. If you are still getting this error, it means you still have classes somewhere that were compiled with JDK 8. Restarting your computer isn't going to fix the problem.

Comment: I have no java 8 installed. I have used clean to remove all compiled files and then recompiled them. And yet it doesn't work. I know the files are recompiled because I can see the "date modified" changes to right after I click clean and also because I have deleted them myself to make sure.

Comment: The only way you can get this error is if you have classes that were compiled with Java 8, and you try to run them on an older version of Java. So, you can say that you checked it, but the truth is that you still somewhere have classes that were compiled with JDK 8... Doesn't the error message tell you for which class this happens?

Comment: @Deleet Have you tried checking ```Project Facets``` and change it to Java 1.7 in your project?

Comment: @Aalkhodiry It says 1.7 in the menu: http://postimg.org/image/4t99ex0hb/.

Comment: @Jesper The first time the error message shows it says `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class jdbc.SQLPublicationMapper)`, refreshing the page changes it slightly to `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jdbc/SQLPublicationMapper`. First version: http://postimg.org/image/cu0xicgbj/, second version: http://postimg.org/image/sfwuzquzp/ Ideas?

Comment: Try deleting everything in the Tomcat work directory, undeploy your webapp, make sure there's nothing in the webapps directory. Then deploy your webapp and start Tomcat again.

Comment: I have done the following: Installed Eclipse and Tomcat7 on a fresh linux Mint 17.1 installation. Transferred the files. Recompiled (with project/clean), verified this was done. Started the server and it doesn't work. The error code is exactly the same. This computer has never had java 8 installed on it because Linux 17.1 comes with java 7.

Comment: I have now tried: Creating a new project (called jsp2), moving the source files (.jsp, .css) and class files into the appropriate folders. Adding the class files to classpath. Deleting the tomcat server. Adding a new server based on jsp2. Starting the server. Same error. (Windows computer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was something more mundane. Apparently the server was not appropriately using the .class files I had given it. These were the files I was updating. Instead it was relying on an old .jar file containing the same classes. Thus, I thought it was using the class files, but it was instead using this old .jar file. This .jar file was exported from java 8. Exporting a new version of this file fixed the issue.

TL;DR Make sure eventual .jar files are also updated, not just .class files.